# Change mysql password using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a change password modal. My problem is that if I want to update my password, it prints: "Incorrect username". How can I solve this problem? I'm using the password = PASSWORD method to hash the password. I'm trying to bind param with the $_SESSION["username"] but it didn't work.

### index.php

```
<form name="resetform" action="changepass.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
                    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>" ></input>
                    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password">
                    <label>Enter New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password">
                    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="password_change" id="submit_btn" value="Change Password" />
                </form>

            <!--display success/error message-->
            <div id="message"></div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var frm = $('#resetform');
        frm.submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = frm.serialize();
            formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#message').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

### changepass.php

```
include_once 'include/connection.php';

    if (isset($_POST['password_change'])) {

        $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['old_password']);
        $newpassword = strip_tags($_POST['new_password']);
        $confirmnewpassword = strip_tags($_POST['con_newpassword']);

        // match username with the username in the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = ? AND password = PASSWORD(?)";

        $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($query->execute() && $query->rowCount()){
            $hash = $query->fetch();
            if ($password == $hash['password']){
                if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE `user` SET `password` = PASSWORD(?) WHERE `username` = ?";

                    $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
                    $query->bindParam(1, $newpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $query->bindParam(2, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    if($query->execute()){
                        echo "Password Changed Successfully!";
                    }else{
                        echo "Password could not be updated";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Passwords do not match!";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Please type your current password accurately!";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Incorrect username";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first major issue is your use of strip_tags, I'm not sure who told you to do that on input, but it's an incredibly bad practice.  If you strip tags on password inputs, you're downgrading the security of any password that uses a `<`.

```
strip_tags('A<dsf$tgee!'); // a strong password of 'A<dsf$tgee!' becomes a weak password of 'A'.
```

---

This condition will also never evaluate to true:

```
$password == $hash['password']
```

Password is hashed via MySQL's PASSWORD() function so the plain text $password will never match the password column in MySQL.